# Automatic desktop extend when second screen is turned on/off

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I'm well aware of how to extend the desktop manually to my second display. But as we all know, it's tedious to go in to resolution setting each time. I tend to shut off my second display, either for full screen applications that can't handle it too well, or simply when I'm not using it.

What I'd like to have is for the desktop to automatically extend only when the second screen is turned on (but still plugged in). I'm not sure if the display signals the hardware if it's on or not, so this might not be possible in the first place.

Does a standard display notify the hardware that the display is turned on? Is there any software that utilizes this to allow you automatic switching of the desktop extension?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you aware of this shortcut to control display extension? *This solution is not as simple as turning your second screen on and off and having it 'just work', but it is much easier than working with the resolution settings dialog.*

Hold <kbd>WIN</kbd> and press <kbd>P</kbd> repeatedly to cycle through the following display options:

- **Computer only** displays your desktop only on your primary screen.
- **Duplicate** replicates your desktop on your primary screen and secondary screen.
- **Extend** displays an extended desktop across two screens.
- **Projector only** displays your desktop only on your secondary screen.

To enable an extended display quickly after turning on your second screen, hold <kbd>WIN</kbd> and press <kbd>P</kbd> until **Extend** is the highlighted option:

[image: Cycling through display options using the keyboard shortcut]

Release the keys to enable an extended display across your two screens.

To return to a single-screen display, hold <kbd>WIN</kbd> and press <kbd>P</kbd> until **Computer only** is the highlighted option. Release the keys to disable the extended display.

Comment: I was surely not aware of that. Great tip, and it's next to as good as what I wanted! Thanks

Comment: This can also be accomplished via DisplaySwitch.exe - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12347530/186623

Answer (score 0):

Place your the other monitor to left hand corner in "arranging monitor", so your mouse wont run away. And now you can turn off the second monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help anyone. I had the problem that when my display times out all the applications that was running on my extended display jumped to my primary display. I then connected my extended monitor to my laptops HDMI port and the extended monitors' VGA port via a HDMI to VGA adapter. The adapter is USB powered and the laptop sees this "powered" device as the extended monitor. Now I can switch off the extended display and when switching on my original apps is displayed correctly on the extended display